# certificate is not validating while calling external api from azure function

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, azure-functions, x509certificate

i am working on an azure function (app service plan) which calls and external api. that api is secured by a certificate.

i have the certificate uploaded in azure function SSL settings. i also have relevant thumbprint in Azure Functions settings.

i am able to pickup the exact same certificate by using its thumbprint.

```
 X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var cert1 = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,                                       
                                    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                    false)[0];
        log.LogInformation(cert1.Subject);
```

but when i make a call using HttpClient i get and SSL error

```
 var _clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        _clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        _clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
        using (var client = new HttpClient(_clientHandler))
        {
         try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                var resp = await client.GetAsync("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

i dont want to bypass validation but to check whats going on i added this code and the chain status is "UntrustedRoot"

```
            _clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
           (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
           {
               log.LogInformation(chain.ChainStatus[0].Status.ToString());
               return true;
           };
```

what is that i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is that i am doing wrong ?

Nothing.  Your client certificate looks like it's probably being properly attached to the request.  The server cert validation callback says that the machine executing the request doesn't trust the certificate chain from the server it sent the request to.

If you compare the certificate chain that you see in Azure (e.g. `foreach (var elem in chain.ChainElements) { log.LogInformation(elem.Certificate.Subject) }`) to one you see from another source and they're the same, then you can make your callback something more like

```
_clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
    {
        X509ChainStatusFlags flags = chain.ChainStatus.Aggregate(
            X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError,
            (f, s) => f | s.Status);

        if (flags == X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot)
        {
            X509Certificate2 presentedRoot =
                chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Length - 1].Certificate;

            return presentedRoot.RawData.SequenceEqual(s_pinnedRootBytes);
        }
    }

    return sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
};
```

Which will only return true if either:

- It would have succeeded without a custom callback
- The only thing wrong with the chain is that it had an untrusted root and the root for the chain is byte-for-byte equal to a copy of the root certificate you've already saved.  (Hard coded, external resource, whatever.)

Comment: yes what you are saying is making sense. 
how did you defined "s_pinnedRootBytes"?

Comment: s_pinnedRootBytes !! is it the "rawdata" of the "cert1" i have in my code ? means the one i am fetching from azure after upload ?

Comment: @RaasMasood No, it's (a copy of) the RawData value from the root authority that issued the server cert; something that you'll have to discover and add to your project.